# How to define custom angularjs-directive that change only Attribute, not (replacing/appending) whole HTML tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive

I'm using `AngularJS` in my project !

I have following `JSON`

```
{
    "headers" :["A","B","C"]
    "rows":[
        ["a","b","c"],
        ["d","e","f"]
    ]
}
```

Also following template:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="header in data.headers" ng-bind="header"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in data.rows">
            <td ng-repeat="item in row track by $index" ng-bind="item"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to change

```
<td ng-repeat="item in row track by $index" ng-bind="item"></td>
```

to

```
<td ng-repeat="item in row track by $index" ng-bind="item" data-my-directive></td>
```

and get this:

```
<td data-title='C'>f</td> // `C` refer to headers[2], because f is row[2]
```

The main qusetion is, how to define a `directive` and force that replace (not add) the `attribute`, not whole `HTML tag`. (**not how to access headers[2] value or something like that**)

As we know, the `template` (or `templateUrl`) of a directive define a complete `HTML tag structure` (for example `<div>SOMETHING</div>`) and replace that (if `replace: true`) or append the template inside the `caller tag`.

**Please note**

Now I have no error or issue, everything working fine, but I need this solution to add more future to my code. I mean I got JSON data on the table and no problem with this part.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box solution that works like replace:true but affect attribute instead of tag.

If you really need this, you can remove the attribute in the link function

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            element.attr('data-title', 'C');
            element.removeAttr('myDirective');
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: this answer "how to define a directive and force that replace one attribute, not whole HTML tag" for me

Comment: your solution add new `data-x` to the tag, but the question is "ow to define a directive and force that **replace** (not add) the attribute, not whole HTML tag"

Comment: Do you mean, you want to remove data-my-directive, ng-bind attributes and replace it with your data-title attribute ?

Comment: not ng-bind, just replacing name of directive with new `data-x` attribute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84596/discussion-between-hugo-g-and-mehdi-dehghani).